# WildFly server backup mode does not allow resource do be managed

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to remove all messages from a Queue created in WildFly 10.1:

```
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/jms-queue=myQueue/:remove-messages
```

But when I run the CLI command I receive the following response message from CLI.

Could someone explain what is the "backup mode" and what can I do to remove all messages?

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"domain-failure-description" => "WFLYMSGAMQ0066: Resource at the address [
    (\"profile\" => \"full-ha\"),
    (\"subsystem\" => \"messaging-activemq\"),
    (\"server\" => \"default\"),
    (\"jms-queue\" => \"myQueue\")
] can not be managed, the server is in backup mode"},
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

Comment: How you remove the all messages from the master (domain)? I tried from the profile and have the same error. I don't understand the solution reading the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the command in your master.

Per example, this is the command for your host `HC-HOSTNAME` and your server is `server-1`:

```
/host=HC-HOSTNAME/server=server-1/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/jms-queue=myQueue:remove-messages
```

Comment: You are correct, it must be applied in the master, but information was only in the comments. Your answer fits the problem better.

Answer (score 1):

In a WildFly domain the backup mode is used for a Host Controller to have a full copy of the domain configuration (as a backup for the current Domain Controller): `Use --backup to keep a copy of the persistent domain configuration even if this host is not a domain controller.`

Comment: I found the doc [Domain Setup](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Domain+Setup) describing that the command `--backup` is used in the Slave server. Does that mean I must connect to Master in order to perform the changes?

Comment: Yes, you should always change your configuration through the master